# Pickers in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

I'm designing a picker in a mobile iOS and Android app. One of the options will open up a dialog box enabling the user to create an option that is not listed in the picker. This new option is then auto populated in the relevant field. Is this possible to do from a dev standpoint? Please see wireframe below.

Many thanks!

[in the screen on the left the user picks a option that lets him create a new item in that list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEQVp.png)

Comment: Depends on your developer's experience in android. As far you as me, yes it is possible for me. But android users may not be familiar with these pickers also this will take worthless efforts to develop. I would suggest stick to native designs.

Comment: @Omkar if the item is clearly visible as an option, why would users not recognize it? What other way do we have for the user to add an item that is not already on the list? Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not against pickers, I am saying that developing iOS like pickers in Android could take much more worthless efforts, you should rather use native spinners.

Comment: @Omkar oh ok! Sorry I miss understood, yes, we will use native pickers, just wanted to make sure there is a corresponding android way to add completely new item to a list from the picker itself. Thanks again!

Comment: Shall I put it as answer then?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is possible to do so in different ways on iOS and Android. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can use `Spinner` in android and `Picker` in iOS.

Below are some tutorials:

[iOS Pickers implementation.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_picker.htm)
[image: ios pickers]

[Android Spinner implementation.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)
[image: android spinner]

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: You are welcome.